# How to add more pages and send a value in node using express?

Tags: json, express, ejs

im new to node js and im doing a task to practice with CRUD actions using express. I have an index.js file for node where i created a server and also use an index.ejs page to show a table with the content of a Json file.

This is the index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 

app.locals.equiposData = require ('./equipos.json'); //this is the json file i show on the ejs file

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/static'))); //this is the folder with my index.ejs file
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index'); //i render the index.ejs file
});
app.listen('3000');
```

And this is my index.ejs file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/styles/style.css"> <!-- se pone public en vez de static pq lo cambie en app-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="titulo card-panel cyan accent-1">
            <h1>Tabla de equipos</h1>
            <p>Cantidad de equipos actualmente: 
                <%  var contar =0; 
                    equiposData.forEach(function(item){ 
                        contar+=1
                    });
                %>
                <%= contar %>
            </p>
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small">Agregar Equipo</a>
        </div>

        <table class="striped centered responsive-table teal lighten-2">
            <thead class="teal accent-1">
              <tr>
                  <th>Nombre Equipo</th>
                  <th>País</th>
                  <th>Fecha Creación</th>
                  <th>Acciones</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
    
            <tbody>
                <% equiposData.forEach(function(item){ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <%= item.name %> </td>
                        <td> <%= item.area.name %> </td>
                        <td> <%= item.founded %> </td>
                        <td> Ver, Editar, Eliminar</td>
                    </tr>
                <% }); %>
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically what that table shows is football teams, the country they are from, the year they were created and it also should allow me to click on the words "Ver" (Show), "Editar" (edit) and "eliminar" (delete)

But i've been reading a lot of posts on how to create new pages, i have some sort of idea... but when i click on the link "Ver" i have to access that item from the row and take it to another page, and show all the json data from that specific item. Each json objects have an ID, so i suppose i could use that to get the item, but i just dont know where to start. I thought about creating a new page like this, on my index.js file:

```
app.get('/ver',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('ver'); //i render the ver.ejs file (the new page i want to add)

});
```

But im not sure how to send the ID of the object to the other page, maybe using the next function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well your question, you're trying to pass a variable to another page by clicking at "Ver" link. You could use something called [Route Params](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.params).
So, by editing your HTML:

```html
            <tbody>
                <% equiposData.forEach(function(item){ %>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <%= item.name %> </td>
                        <td> <%= item.area.name %> </td>
                        <td> <%= item.founded %> </td>
                        <td> <a href="/ver/<%=item.id%>">Ver</a>, Editar, Eliminar</td>
                    </tr>
                <% }); %>
            </tbody>
```

After you need to update your `app.get()` method to receive a parameter passed by route:

```js
app.get('/ver/:id', (req, res) => {
    var id = req.params.id;
    // Do whatever you need here...
    res.render('ver', {value: id} );
});
```

So in "Ver" page you now have access to the id value passed by `render()` method. You can pass whatever other values, objects and so on.
For testing purposes, at "Ver" page you can try: `<%= value %>` to see what you're getting.

Comment: You're welcome!  You can also replicate this behavior to other links. I recommend to search more about Routing (in your case, you're using Route Params, but also we have Query Params and Body Params to help us too).